# Recover password that contains known phrase

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat

I want to recover a long password with hashcat. The password contains a phrase and between the words are special character sequences. These sequences are limited (< 4) and *unknown*. But the set of characters to pick from is known and small (< 6).

**Example Phrase:** Barbara walks the dog
**Special Characters:** $%-"
**Possible Password:** Barbara%walks$$%the$dog

I tried to generate all the passwords with regex but that file grew too big. How do I achieve this with hashcat e.g. their rule system?

Comment: Why not produce a wordlist based on these characteristics in a language of your choice?

Comment: That would still produce too large of a file, no? I think OP wants to know how to do this in memory.

Comment: Exactly. It quickly grew to a couple of gigabytes so I figured another approach will be better.

Comment: Is the phrase known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mask attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack) seems to be a good solution.

Generate a `.hcmask` file with the following lines:

```
$%-",Barbara?1walks?1the?1dog
$%-",Barbara?1walks?1the?1?1dog
...
```

And so on, where each line is has differences places for the special characters (`?1`).

Since you know the phrase, and because the set of characters is small, the total number of lines should be very low.

Comment: I already tried to generate all the passwords but it looked like that file was going to be very big. Is there a way to generate them in memory while cracking? Or is it easier to just work with a really big file?

Comment: It's not about generating passwords, but generating masks. `?1` means "any of the characters at the begining of the line", which should greatly decrease the size of the file.